# What happens when I click "No" to "X wants to be able to chat" in Gmail? Will he or she know?

Tags: gmail, chat

I don't want to be rude. But I don't want to chat with this person in Gmail. Will he/she be notified or otherwise know if I say no to his/her chat request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they will not receive any notification about your action.
The user will continue to see you in their list with the "Invited" status.

Comment: Follow up: What do I say to this person when I see him/her in person so that he/she doesn't feel rejected?

Comment: If the other person asks, I would politely give them an alternative way for them to contact you, that you prefer them to use instead of via Gchat. I use the same technique for "rejecting" people I don't really know on Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

S/he sent you a chat invitation. Whether you press "No" or leave it alone, whether s/he gets a notification or not, either way s/he don't get to chat to you. So, the end result is same.

No, s/he wont get any notification.

P.S. - BTW, if that person doesn't get a notification, that's even more rude, that means you are ignoring him/her.

Comment: I respect your opinion, but I think it's my right to decide who can and cannot see my Gchat status. Let me know if you think there are any other ways I can respectfully say "no."